# Get latency from host in C++

Tags: c++, latency, ping

Using C++, I would like to use a command/class to get the latency time from pinging a host to use in my program.  I tried using the ping command but there was no easy way to gather the time since its included with other statistical information.  I was hoping for an easier approach.

Comment: Which OS? Windows, Linux or ?

Answer (score 7):

The [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) tool is usually implemented in C and works by sending [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) [Echo request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping#Echo_request) packets over a [raw socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket),. The system time is recorded -- usually with [gettimeofday](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/gettimeofday.html) on under [posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) -- when the Echo request is made and again when an [Echo reply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping#Echo_reply) (if any) is received to determine the round-trip time. You can put the same functionality in your C++ application using [sockets](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#theory).

Otherwise, extracting the information from a ping system call is probably easier than you think. The key is to open a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) to allow reading of the [standard output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdout#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) of the ping command (see [`popen`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/popen.html) or [`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b(VS.80).aspx)).  A [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (e.g. "time=([0-9]*)") could be used to pluck out the desired data. If you don't have a regex library available, then extracting this data only requires fairly trivial string manipulation. The [STL string class](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html) provides several algorithms that may be of use.

Comment: Raw sockets require "root" or "Administrator" privileges.  On UNIX the ping program is suid so you can run it as a normal user, but you can't write your own version unless your program runs as root.  This may or may not be a problem for you.  The RE approach is probably better.

Comment: I understand this but the return value from a ping command is either 0 or 1. Is there an easier way than rediecting the standard output to a flatfile?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm able to figure out how to parse the information that I need when I run the command from the command prompt.  However, in my program, the return value for a ping command is either 0 or 1.  Is there an easier way to get my info rather than redirecting the output to a flatfile?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't like regexes you can always loop through the output, looking for t followed by i followed by m followed by e followed by = by just stepping through the output string one piece at a time. store the pointer to the char after =, then step through futher and replace the next space by a zero. you now have a string with the latency, converting to a number can be done with the existing conversion functions.

e.g. if the output is in char* output with length stored in unsigned int length and the matched string needs to go in char* match...

```
for(unsigned int i = 4; i < length; ++i)
{
  if(output[i] == '=')
  {
    if((output[i-4] = 't') && (output[i-3] = 'i') && (output[i-2] = 'm') && (output[i-1] = 'e'))
    {
      match = &(output[i+1]);
      while(output[i] != ' ') ++i;
      output[i] = 0;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

regexes are nicer though... they make your code look a lot a tider and readable. although if you don't have a library for them it will be faster to just implement it like this... :)

Comment: shouldn't `(output[i-4] = 't')` be a comparison ( `(output[i-4] == 't')`) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you can use win32 api function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho2.